# Alternative to onload location.href?

Tags: html, css, redirect, mod-rewrite, onload

Hi there stackoverflow,

I have been playing around a lot with CSS3 lately, more often than not using it for many things for which I had resorted to Javascript previously.

Just curious: I am wondering whether there is a way of automatically scrolling to an on-page anchor as soon as the page loads, something like `<body onload='location.href="#someanchor"'>`, but without using Javascript. Like, CSS3-only if possible. Haven't come up with a way yet.

I am also thinking of maybe an .htaccess RewriteRule involving the [NE] flag, but my experiments so far only led to redirection loops.

Any nice tweaks? :-)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible using CSS nor CSS3 alone.CSS/CSS3 is only supposed to affect the looks and layout of your content.

Comment: If it has to animate the scroll, JavaScript is your only option. If you just want the user to arrive at the location a.s.a.p., put the hash in the link that leads to the page. There is nothing mod rewrite can do unless you're already redirecting to that page, and forgetting to add the hash.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers.